# Encode / Decode string to UTF-8 with Emojis

Tags: ios, utf-8, swift2

I'm developping a messaging app between Android an iOS (Swift 2.2).

Users must be able to **send and receive Emojis** : `Hello`

I need to encode emojis to `UTF-8` instead of `Unicode`.

Here my code to encode / decode from `Unicode` :

```
static func decodeUnicode(input: String) -> String {
    let ns = NSString(string: input)
    let data:NSData = ns.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    if let decoded = NSString(data:data,encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
        return decoded
    }

    return ""
}

static func encodeUnicode(input: String) -> String {
    let data:NSData = input.dataUsingEncoding(NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)!

    if let decoded = NSString(data:data,encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
        return decoded
    }

    return ""
}
```

Encoding have to be compatible with Android decoding.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "UTF-8 instead of Unicode"? UTF-8 is a _character encoding_ and Unicode is a _character set_.

Comment: You have a misconception about encoding/decoding. Encoding translates a string (more or less an array of characters) into binary data. Decoding does the opposite. So your `encodeUnicode` function needs to return a `Data` object. But most likely your are solving the wrong problem anyway. How do you transmit the message? There's already some sort of encoding there. Show that code.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification ! To explain the problem, I'm using a server that store text. If i'm sending data without doing anything, emojis became : "??". Have to avoid that ?

Comment: What protocol do you use with the server? JSON? XML? Some binary form? Show the relevant code. There's already an encoding involved there. You might just not be aware of it. And what setup do you use on the server side? Java? .NET? Some database?

Comment: Don't know about every thing except DB : SQL Server using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI

Comment: With SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI, you cannot store emojis. This character set does not comprise them. Most likely, the emojis are not lost on the iOS side, but on the server side. Check the entire way from iOS to SQL Server to see where the emojis are converted to "??". Then apply the necessary fixes. In SQL Server, it might require to use a different character set or NVARCHAR column.

Comment: Thank you I solved my problem !